# Public transport maps editor

Tags: windows, gratis, linux

I am looking for an easiest way to create schemas of public transport like [this one](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2009/11/23/article-0-0753EE5D000005DC-872_964x676.jpg):

[image: Public transport of London]

Ideal way how would I'd like to create a schema:

- Put stations/stops on target point (ideally some grid-like system, so they are all in same distance or multiples of that distance)
- Connect stops with coloured lines (marking all lines going between these stops)
- Add text as name of stop
- Add text marking end of an line
- All stuff related to one line is in same colour

Nice-to-have features:

- Hovering over one line or number highlights whole line
- Zoomable / scrollable (similar to Google Maps)
- file can be saved in a format i can open and edit later in same software

Of course I could create it in Windows paint or something similar, but that would be very painful.

Oh, and also:

- Price - ideally free
- platform - Windows or Linux

Answer (score 1):

It might look a bit odd, but what about circuit diagram type software? That would fulfill most of the requirements you mentioned. How about TinyCAD? https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinycad/

Comment: Ncie lateral thinking :-)